# How to compare 2 list/array with python using for loops?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to compare ListA[0] to ListB[0]...etc.

```
ListA = [itemA, itemB, itemC]
ListB = [true, false, true]

for item in ListA:
    if ListB[item] == True:
        print"I have this item"
```

Current problem is that [item] is not a number, so ListB[item] will not work. What is the correct way if I want to do something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.compress`:

```
Docstring:
compress(data, selectors) --> iterator over selected data

Return data elements corresponding to true selector elements.
Forms a shorter iterator from selected data elements using the
selectors to choose the data elements.
```

---

```
In [1]: from itertools import compress

In [2]: l1 = ['a','b','c','d']

In [3]: l2 = [True, False, True,False]

In [4]: for i in compress(l1,l2):
   ...:     print 'I have item: {0}'.format(i)
   ...:     
I have item: a
I have item: c
```

Answer (score 7):

You can iterate through the **lists** this way.

```
for a, b in zip(ListA, ListB):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do something like this:

```
[ a for a,b in zip(ListA,ListB) if b==True ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate.

See this example:

http://codepad.org/sJ31ytWk

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for item, have_it in zip(ListA, ListB):
    if have_it:
        print "I have item", item
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for name,value in itertools.izip(ListA, ListB):
    if value == True:
        print "Its true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare each element of ListA with the corresponding element of ListB (in other words the elements at the same index numbers), you can use a for loop that iterates over the index **numbers** rather than iterating over the actual elements of one list.
So your code would be:  (note that range(len(ListA)-1) gives you a list of the numbers from 0 to the length of ListA, minus 1 since it's 0-indexing)

```
for i in range(len(ListA)-1):
      //ListA[i] will give you the i'th element of ListA
      //ListB[i] will give you the i'th element of ListB
```